# python + windows: run exe as if it's unrelated to the current process

Tags: python, windows, process, subprocess, pywin32

I know I can use `subprocess.Popen` to run an executable, and potentially redirect stdin and stdout to files / using pipes to my process. Is there a way to run an executable such that the spawned process has no relation to the current Python process, however? Meaning, I want to start a process in the same way as if I would double-click on the .exe, or type in its name into Start->Run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, see [os.startfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=startfile#os.startfile).